# _grokparsefailure without Filters

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have some simple logstash configuration:

```
input {
    syslog {
        port => 5140
        type => "fortigate"
    }
}

output {
    elasticsearch {
        cluster => "logging"
        node_name => "logstash-logging-03"
        bind_host => "10.100.19.77"
    }
}
```

Thats it. Problem is that the documents that end up in elasticsearch do contain a _grokparsefailure:

```
{
  "_index": "logstash-2014.12.19",
  ...
  "_source": {
    "message": ...",
    ...
    "tags": [
      "_grokparsefailure"
    ],
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

How come? There are no (grok) filters...

Comment: How are you invoking Logstash? If you're passing a directory via `-f`, does that directory contain any other files?

Comment: I guess I just fount the issue: the syslog input already does some gorky stuff internally. Since the logs I want to receive do not have a syslog format, I get the tags... I try to get it working via udp/tcp inputs and post updates here...

Answer (score 0):

OK: The syslog input obviously makes use of gork internally. Therefore, if some other log format than "syslog" hits the input a "_grokparsefailure" will occure.

Instead, I just used "tcp" and "udp" inputs to achieve the required result (I was not aware of them before).

Cheers